# how to monitor java jre 8 on zabbix via JMX technology

Tags: 14.04, java, tomcat

how to monitor java jre 8 that running on tomcat8 via jmx technology? server os is ubuntu 14.04 LTS and monitoring platform is zabbix 2.2.

Answer (score 0):

It should be easy with any plugin for JMX that Zabbix has as a platform. Anyway, if you're not restricted by only Open Source options, you can check out Pandora FMS Enterprise Edition as an alternative. Yeah, you have to pay for it, but their [JMX plugin](http://library.pandorafms.com/index.php?sec=Library&sec2=repository&lng=en&action=view_PUI&id_PUI=327) works.